# About RDBMS Concept

Tags: rdbms

Can any give me overview of Entity,attribute,Tuples and Domain set. and E-R Model Diagram and 1st,2nd and 3rd Normalforms.

Comment: There are many, many web resources on this topic.  Google is your friend; you could also start with the wikipedia articles on the subject.

Comment: This is clearly homework assignment, this is basically one of the entry-level questions to RDBMS'.

Comment: I'm conducting a survey.  Are you preparing for an interview?

Answer (score 1):

As indeed a comment has stated, a decent first place to look is @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database